# how to prevent reading when hazelcast map is locked

Tags: hazelcast

for there are lots of data should be put into hazelcast map, I want to prevent reading from others when the data is putting into the map.

is there any way to realize it?

for example:

`map a = map(1,000,000,000) // a has 1,000,000,000 elements
map b = map(2,000) // b has 200 emlemnts`

i want to put all of b into a ;

the elements of b should be accessed after all of these are put into map a;

if the elements of map b haven't been put into map a entirely, the elements of map b couldn't be accessed.

### use case:

```
map a ={1,2,3,4,5} 
map b ={a,b,c,d,e}
```

print a // result {1,2,3,4,5}

```
foreach item in b

a.put item
```

print a // **result {1,2,3,4,5}**

```
end foreach
```

print a //result {1,2,3,4,5,a,b,c,d,e}

i want to merge these two maps.while, map b's elements couldn't be accessed via map a before merging finished.

## my solutions

thank all the people for their help.
after reading the hazelcast manual, I choose the transactionalMap to resolve this problem.

transactionalMap is READ_COMMITED islate. it could suspend reading map(1) threads when the transaction is updating map(1).

``` java
    static Runnable tx = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

```
        try {
            logger.info("start transaction...");
            TransactionContext txCxt = hz.newTransactionContext();
            txCxt.beginTransaction();
            TransactionalMap<Object, Object> map = txCxt.getMap("map");

            try {
                logger.info("before put map(1)");
                Thread.sleep(300);
                map.put("1", "1"); // reader1 is blocked
                logger.info("after put map(1)");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                map.put("2", "2"); // reader2 is blocked
                logger.info("after put map(2)");
                Thread.sleep(500);
                txCxt.commitTransaction();
                logger.info("transaction committed");
            } catch (RuntimeException t) {
                txCxt.rollbackTransaction();
                throw t;
            }

            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            logger.info("Finished testmap size:{}, testmap(1):{}, testmap(2):{} ", testmap.size(), testmap.get("1"),
                    testmap.get("2"));

            Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
            logger.info("system exit.");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
};
```

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your motivation / use-case? You can use transactions, but that could have a bad impact on performance. Alternatively you could use manual locking - see `ILock`.

However both these techniques should be used as a last-resort - when you have no chance to design your application differently.

Comment: thanks , i've add some use case. ILock couldn't prevent reading from other threads.

Comment: Why do you think so? An ILock locks around the whole operation, sure it'll prevent reading from other threads but every access needs to be guarded by the lock :) That's what +Jaromir was talking about when he said "performance impact".

Comment: thanks in advance. I choose transaction map to resolve it, for I pay more attention to the map data.  in my case, there is only one writing thread, and much more reading threads. so i could pay more attention to the writing thread.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by locking the segments in Map b while adding to it. Once pushing the entries to Map a is complete, you can unlock the segments.
There will be performance implications with this methods though as it requires an extra step of locking/unlocking.